# get, access and modify element values for an numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I once saw the following code segment

```
import numpy as np
nx=3
ny=3
label = np.ones((nx, ny))
mask=np.zeros((nx,ny),dtype=np.bool)
label[mask]=0
```

The `mask` generated is a bool array

```
[[False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]]
```

If I would like to assign some elements in mask to other values, for instance, I have been trying to use `mask[2,1]="True"`, but it did not work without changing the corrsponding entry as I expected.  What's the correct way to get access and change the value for an numpy array. In addition, what does `label[mask]=0` do? It seems to me that it tries to use each mask entry value to assign the corrsponding label entry value.

Comment: Maybe read up on [`boolean-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays)?

Comment: `label[mask] = 0` will do nothing, since your `mask` array is all `false`. This would work if some elements of `mask` were `true`. An accessiing and assigning a value to an `np.array` is syntatically same as acessing python list as far as I'm concerned. There's also an option to acess arrays with arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code snippet with some comments that might help you make sense of this. I would suggest you look into the link that @Divakar provided and look into [boolean-indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays).

```
# a two dimensional array with random values
arr = np.random.random((5, 5))

# assign mask to a two dimensional array (same shape as arr)
# that has True for every element where the corresponding
# element in arr is greater than 0.5
mask = arr > 0.5

# assign all the elements in arr that are greater than 0.5 to 0
arr[mask] = 0

# the above can be more concisely written as:
arr[arr>0.5] = 0

# you can change the mask any way you want

# here I invert the mask
inv_mask = np.invert(mask)

# assign all the values in arr less than 0.5 to 1
arr[inv_mask] = 1
```